# Validar senha com Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, condição

Estou tentando fazer um exercício onde preciso validar uma senha, tentei desse formato porém o condicional `if` parece ignorar a segunda condição. Não consegui encontrar o problema, o que pode ser?

```
{
        let senha = 'Guilhe3rme';
        const regex = /[0-9]/;


         if((senha.length > 5 && senha.length < 10) && (regex.test(senha) == true)){  
               console.log("Senha válida!")
         }else{
               console.log("Senha inválida!");
         }
}
```

No console sai apenas o "Senha inválida!", se eu remover a segunda condição o console exibe o "Senha válida!"

No exercício é necessário a senha ter entre 5 e 10 caracteres e conter pelo menos um dígito de 0-9.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 7):

`Guilhe3rme` tem 10 letras, a segunda condição exige que tenha **menos que** 10 para ser verdadeira, portanto, a segunda é falsa. Como ela está ligada com as demais com `&&` que exige que todas condições sejam verdadeira para dar resultado final verdadeiro, então cairá no `else`.

Note que o operador `<` quer dizer que tem que ser menor que aquilo, aquele número não entra. Se sua intenção era ser até 10, então deveria usar `<= 10` ou `< 11`. Assim como a primeira condição exige um mínimo de 6 caracteres e não 5 como talvez esteja pensando.

Depois teve uma edição na pergunta que deixa isso mais claro, então, na minha interpretação, já que o enunciado é ambíguo e não diz se é inclusivo ou exclusivo, e se o é nos dois lados, realmente a condição parece que deveria ser:

```
if (senha.length >= 5 && senha.length <= 10 && regex.test(senha)) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Operators/Validation.js).

Não verifiquei se o RegEx está correto.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!

Comment: Tenho minhas dúvidas, de qualquer forma dê uma olhada no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.